How to perform a zuluCrypt "Create Encrypted Container in Hard Drive" but as a Linux command line?
I have long been in the process of converting my manual steps to create a new backup disks into an automated script. The only part I have left is the initial "creation" of the disk, meaning whatever zuluCrypt does behind the scenes when you use this menu option:
Create => Encrypted Container in Hard Drive

I have searched for a way to display the command(s) that zuluCrypt uses under the hood, but there seems to be no such thing. I also cannot comprehend its source code to see what it's actually doing: https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt/blob/master/zuluCrypt-gui/createvolume.cpp seems to not have any mention of "cryptsetup" as a command being run, for example.
I assume that it must involve a cryptsetup command, perhaps with makefs as well or something like that (since it creates a ready-to-use LUKS2-encrypted ext4 file system on the disk). I want my script to be identical to this step which I've manually done so many times now, in order to ensure consistency. I'd rather not "guess" the command based on what it "probably" runs.
How would I recreate these exact options from the GUI, as a command line?
screenshot

cryptsetup also offers libcryptsetup library, which seems to be what zuluCrypt is using. So there is no literal command to extract...

@frostschutz Well, if that's the case, that... sucks. I'd love to be able to make sure that I exactly replicate what I've been doing through the zuluCrypt GUI...
